# cant create shared library on RPI (Raspbian)

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I want to create shared libray on RPI. this is successfuly done in ubuntu desktop PC, but not on RPI (Raspbian)

shared.c

```
#include "shared.h"
unsigned int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    printf("\n Inside add()\n");
    return (a+b);
}
```

shared.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern unsigned int add(unsigned int a, unsigned int b);
```

I compiled the library with those two commands

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC shared.c
gcc -shared -o libshared.so shared.o
```

main code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"shared.h"
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a = 1;
    unsigned int b = 2;
    unsigned int result = 0;

    result = add(a,b);

    printf("\n The result is [%u]\n",result);
    return 0;
}

gcc -L /library path/ -Wall main.c -o main -lshared
```

I got this error

```
fatal error: shared.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have shared.h in the same directory as main.c when you compile (or in /usr/local/include or other include directory on the search path).